# Change transform.localPosition to act like transform.Translate with Space.Self

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

I run into the problem with moving object regarding to its rotation. The thing is that I'm changing object position by assigning new `transform.localPosition` value. In specific cases I want to modify assigned value by slightly changing `z` axis (height) of the object.

I tried to do it with use of `transform.up`. I expected move along local `z` axis (like in Unity scene preview), but it doesn't work as expected.

`transform.Translate(Vector3.up, Space.Self)` works exactly as I want, but as I said I want to combine it with `transform.localPosition` i already use. How should I modify passed Vector3 so it works correctly?

---

The class below is used to simulate move of an object around sphere. For example plane flying around Earth. I adjust plane rotation so it's chassis is facing Earth. Object is moving on the Earth surface though. I want to move it slightly up so it flies. That's why I want to move it along local `z` axis as it is distance from the core of the Earth.

Full class snippet (I'm using LeanTouch package)

```
public Transform lookAtTarget;
RaycastHit hit;
RaycastHit lastHit;

public float rotationSmoothTime = 0.3F;
public float moveSmoothTime = 0.3F;
private Vector3 rotationVelocity = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 moveVelocity = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 lastNewRightDir;

protected virtual void Awake ()
{
    Use.UpdateRequiredSelectable (gameObject);
    lastNewRightDir = transform.right;
}

void Update ()
{
    var fingers = Use.GetFingers ();
    if (fingers.Count < 1)
    {
        Move (lastFingerScreenPosition, Vector2.zero);
        return;
    }
    LeanFinger finger = fingers[0];
    Move (finger.ScreenPosition, finger.ScreenDelta);
    lastFingerScreenPosition = finger.ScreenPosition;
}

public void Move (Vector2 fingerScreenPosition, Vector2 scaledDelta)
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (fingerScreenPosition);
    LayerMask mask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Interactable");

    bool newHit = Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, float.PositiveInfinity, mask);

    Vector3 rightDir = transform.right;
    Vector3 newRightDir = lastNewRightDir;

    Vector3 targetPosition = lastHit.point;

    if (newHit)
    {
        targetPosition = hit.point;
        lastHit = hit;
    }
    else if (lastHit.distance == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Vector3 forwardDir = (targetPosition - lookAtTarget.position).normalized;

    if (targetPosition != transform.position && scaledDelta != Vector2.zero)
    {
        newRightDir = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized;
        lastNewRightDir = newRightDir;
    }

    rightDir = Vector3.SmoothDamp (rightDir, newRightDir, ref rotationVelocity, rotationSmoothTime);
    Vector3 upwardDir = Vector3.Cross (forwardDir, rightDir);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (forwardDir, upwardDir);


    transform.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.localPosition, targetPosition, ref moveVelocity, moveSmoothTime);
}}
```

Before `transform.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.localPosition, targetPosition, ref moveVelocity, moveSmoothTime);` the `targetPosition` value should be adjusted so object moves 1 unit alongside local z axis.

Comment: @Zibelas I'm setting it this way. The targetPosition variable is based on raycast hit.

`transform.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.localPosition, targetPosition, ref moveVelocity, moveSmoothTime);`

The thing is that `y` axis is height of the object. During move object should be lets say 1 unit above ground. So i want to add this value to `targetPosition`. `Vector3.up` won't work correctly as I want to apply this 1 unit based on transform rotation, not global rotation. I though `transform.up` would work this way, but clearly I'm wrong.

Comment: @Zibelas I updated my question with class snippet. I hope it helps with understanding my issue.

Comment: why are you using transform.rotation and not transform.localRotation?

Comment: To be honest I didn't think setting height would be such a problem and it was easier for me to calculate it that way. I don't think it's a problem though. Plane is rotated correctly and setting it using transform.localRotation would give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform.up` is a vector in world space, but `transform.localPosition` moves an object in its *parent's* space. If the parent (or grandparent, etc) is rotated, then these two spaces can differ.

To get the object's up vector relative to its parent coordinate system, just multiply:

```
Vector3 localUpInParentSpace = transform.localRotation * Vector3.up;
```

Then you can add it to your localPosition:

```
upwardShift = 1.0f; // Substitute whatever distance you want to move here.
Vector3 shiftedLocalPosition = transform.localPosition + localUpInParentSpace * upwardShift;
```

This moves along the object's local y+ axis. If you want to move along the object's local z+ axis, use `Vector3.forward` instead of `Vector3.up`.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was trying to do!